# Why am I getting a ConnectionResetError for my basic python UDP client?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, udpclient

I'm on a 2020.4 Kali Linux VM on VMWare Workstation 16 Player and I'm working with the Black Hat Python book by Justin Seitz. Right in the beginning of Chapter 2 he introduces a basic UDP client but for some reason, I get thrown a ConnectionResetError every time because either the port I'm sending to or the port I'm receiving from is occupied. I then added a line to make it bind to the address I'm sending to and it worked. Is it not automatically binding when I sendto()? If I'm pentesting, I shouldn't need the password/admin to bind when I make a UDP client.

**Here is my code:**

```py
import socket


address = ('127.0.0.1', 80)

# Create a socket object.
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# I commented this out just for testing reasons.
# client.bind(address)

# Send some data.
client.sendto(b'AAABBBCCC', address)

# Receive some data.
data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)

print(data)
```

**Here's the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\udp_client.py", line 15, in <module>
    data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I apologize in advance if this is some dumb mistake on my part.

### EDIT:

I changed the code to use a different port (`65536`) yet now it just doesn't print anything or end the script, it just keeps running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you try using a port other than port 80 (default for all HTTP traffic) which is likely being used constantly and isn't a good port to try and hold onto, try port numbers > 1023

Comment: It definitely got rid of my error, but now it doesn't print anything to the console or even end at all.

Comment: must be the line where you receive data: client.recvdata(4096) that's holding the connection waiting for the data, does the server receive the data you send at first successfully? double check by printing that data on the server side

Comment: The IP I'm using is the loopback IP, a.k.a. localhost, so it should receive the string I sent to myself in my sendto() call. The buffer size passed into recvfrom() is also a big enough size.

Comment: you need to have a SEPARATE server process running waiting for that data, you can't send and receive on the same process. and that's kind of irrelevant but loopback is not the same as localhost.

Comment: Right, sorry about that. I'll make a server real quick.

Comment: Alright my bad, the book didn't include that it required a server and also didn't tell me how to write a UDP server, so I just found out and it worked. Thank you!